# Ansible: Is it possible to search replace single word

Tags: linux, ansible

In the [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/lineinfile_module.html) module, it replaces the full line.

If the line is long I have to repeat the whole line again.

Let us suppose I want to replace the single word in the file:

```
#abc.conf
This is my horse
```

this is the playbook:

```
 - lineinfile: dest=abc.conf
               state=present
               regexp='horse'
               line='This is my dog'
               backup=yes
```

is there any way to achieve someting like `sed 's/horse/dog/g'` ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use [backreferences](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/release1.5.3/library/files/lineinfile#L64) to retrieve other parts(that should not be changed) of the line:

```
 - lineinfile: dest=abc.conf
               state=present
               regexp='^(.*)horse(.*)$'
               line='\1dog\2'
               backup=yes
               backrefs=yes
```

Comment: What if the word to replace with isn't 'dog' but some ip address like 127.0.1.1? All I'm getting is some weird character....

Comment: for ip address change the regex `regexp="127\.0\.0\.1.*"`

Answer (score 30):

New module [replace](http://docs.ansible.com/replace_module.html) available since `1.6` version:

```
- replace:
    dest=abc.conf
    regexp='horse'
    replace='dog'
    backup=yes
```

Comment: It doesn't work like this; ERROR: There was an error while parsing the task ".... backup=yes".
Make sure quotes are matched or escaped properly

Answer (score 2):

If you need to do more replace operations in one block and you have the file locally, you might want to consider using template, which substitutes variables in the template file and copies the file to the remote:

```
- template: src=/mytemplates/foo.j2 dest=/etc/file.conf
```

In the local file you can write a variable with ansible sintax like

```
{{variable}}
```

and it will be substituted if it is in the scope of the script. [Here](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/template_module.html) the docs.